# How to get Latitude and Longitude Bounds from Google Maps x y and zoom parameters

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have seen some questions with similar titles, but they seem to be referring to `x` and `y` pixel coordinates.

I am asking about the actual tile numbers of `x` and `y` from Google Maps `getTile()` function:

To clarify the question...

Given the x, y, and zoom parameters in the getTile() function, how can I find the latitude and longitude bounds of the tile?

```
CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {

    var x = coord.x,
    y = coord.y,
    url = "http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x="+x+"&y="+y+"&z="+zoom;
    //other stuff   
}
```

The only reason at the moment that I need this is that I want to determine the maximum zoom level at this tile projection.  From this link: [Maximum Zoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom), it states that in order to find the maximum zoom, I will need a latitude and longitude value using `getMaxZoomAtLatLng()`.  So if I can get the bounds, then I can use any latitude and longitude points within the bounds to find my max Zoom.

Alternatives I have thought of were creating an image and checking if the src url had an error (this seems like a terrible idea to me, as I would be making many bad requests just to check if imagery existed).

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {/*imagery exists*/ }
img.onerror = function() {/*past maximum zoom*/ }
img.src = url;
```

EDIT:

After further investigation, I realize that the `getMaxZoomAtLatLng()` function is using an ajax call which will not fit into my plans.  But I still am interested in how to find the latitude and longitude boundaries of a given tile ( that could be useful for other applications ).

Comment: Why the down vote?  I have worked very hard at phrasing and preparing this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming a basic google-map using mercator-projection and a tileSize of 256x256:

The number of tiles on each(x-axis and y-axis) is `Math.pow(2,zoom)`, so on zoom `0` the map is using 1 tile, on zoom `1` 4 tiles, on zoom `2` 16 tiles and so on.

First calculate the southWest/northeast-points of the tile.

the size of a tile (in points) is `256/Math.pow(2,zoom)`

southWest-point:

```
x = tile.x * tileSizeInPoints
y = (tile.y * tileSizeInPoints) + tileSizeInPoints
```

northEast-point:

```
x = (tile.x * tileSizeInPoints) + tileSizeInPoints
y = tile.y * tileSizeInPoints
```

These points must be translated to LatLngs. When you use a map you may use the method [fromLatLngToPoint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Projection) of the maps projection.

For a custom implementation take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates.

A possible API-independant implementation:

```
MERCATOR={

  fromLatLngToPoint:function(latLng){
     var siny =  Math.min(Math.max(Math.sin(latLng.lat* (Math.PI / 180)), 
                                   -.9999),
                          .9999);
     return {
      x: 128 + latLng.lng * (256/360),
      y: 128 + 0.5 * Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) * -(256 / (2 * Math.PI))
     };
  },

  fromPointToLatLng: function(point){

     return {
      lat: (2 * Math.atan(Math.exp((point.y - 128) / -(256 / (2 * Math.PI)))) -
             Math.PI / 2)/ (Math.PI / 180),
      lng:  (point.x - 128) / (256 / 360)
     };

  },

  getTileAtLatLng:function(latLng,zoom){
    var t=Math.pow(2,zoom),
        s=256/t,
        p=this.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
        return {x:Math.floor(p.x/s),y:Math.floor(p.y/s),z:zoom};
  },

  getTileBounds:function(tile){
    tile=this.normalizeTile(tile);
    var t=Math.pow(2,tile.z),
        s=256/t,
        sw={x:tile.x*s,
            y:(tile.y*s)+s},
        ne={x:tile.x*s+s,
            y:(tile.y*s)};
        return{sw:this.fromPointToLatLng(sw),
               ne:this.fromPointToLatLng(ne)
              }
  },
  normalizeTile:function(tile){
    var t=Math.pow(2,tile.z);
    tile.x=((tile.x%t)+t)%t;
    tile.y=((tile.y%t)+t)%t;
    return tile;
  }

}
```

call `MERCATOR.getTileBounds()` by supplying a single object as argument with the following format:

```
{
 x:tileIndexX,
 y:tileIndexY,
 z:zoom 
}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/55Nke/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/55Nke/)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all that info in one place.

Comment: what about leaflet tiles?

Comment: Great answer, but when I apply with tile size = 64, It seems not working. Of course, I replaced 256 = 64, 128 = 32 in `getTileBounds` and `fromPointToLatLng` function. I mean, Can you get a function with `tileSize` as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this entirely helps with the bounds, but to find an easy display of the tile coordinates I went here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

And to typescript on the line:

```
  const chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.76781028848151, 150.73644505329204
);
```

Change the lat/long to wherever you want... And they have a nice UI that calculates all the changes on zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google maps tiling system is similar to the Bings maps tiling system. The tiles start from the upper left in the lower right and each tile is 256x256:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.